# Why is this nesting for loop getting a null value?

Tags: swift

```
func twoSum(_ nums: [Int], _ target: Int) -> [Int] {
var num1: Int = 0
var num2: Int = 0

for i in nums {

    let test1: Int = nums.index(of: i)!

    for x in nums {

        let test2: Int = nums.index(of: x)!

        if (i + x == target && test1 != test2) {

            num1 = x
            num2 = i

        }

    }

}

let out1: Int = nums.index(of: num1)!
let out2: Int = nums.index(of: num2)!

let outArray: [Int] = [out1, out2]

return outArray

}
```

Hi everyone. I'm trying to get the above code to run. This is my take on the Two Sum problem at LeetCode. Basically you give an array and a "target" and the code returns the indices of the numbers which when added are equal to "target".

```
twoSum([2,7,11,15], 9)
twoSum([1,5,2,3,5,10], 15)
```

So far, these 2 examples are working fine and they correctly return `[0, 1]` and `[1, 5]` respectively.

However with this example, `twoSum([3,3], 6)`, i get unexpectedly found nil error. Does anyone know why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `enumerated()` to avoid force unwrapping
*(and I made some changes in your code)*:

```
func twoSum(_ nums: [Int], _ target: Int) -> [Int] {
    for (test1, i) in nums.enumerated() {
        for (test2, x) in nums.enumerated() {
            if (i + x == target && test1 != test2) {
                return [test1, test2]
            }
        }
    }
    return [0, 0] // but may be you should return nil in this case
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `test1 == test2` neither `num1` or `num2` will be defined, resulting in a crash when you force unwrap `nums.index(of: num1)`

Try this instead:

```
for i in nums {
    for x in nums {
        if (i + x == target && i != x) {
            num1 = x
            num2 = i
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: correct! I think the problem was originally solved in a poor way, and I would prefer Aleksandr's method instead

Answer (score 0):

nums.index(of: x) doesn't return the index from which x was originally taken. It searches for x and returns the index of the first element of nums that is equal to x.

Your array nums is [3, 3]. If you search for nums [0] = 3, index(of: 3) returns 0. If you search for nums [1] which is also 3, index(of: 3) returns 0 again. It doesn't return 1. index searches for the number, it doesn't know where that number came from.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I'm gonna try it out.